# Remove section in billing information paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I would like to know when the user click on this section No PayPal account? Pay using your credit or debit card

> Question Is it possible to remove this section `You need a PayPal account for this purchase.` Because some users may not have a pay pal account just want to pay by credit card.

I am using paypal sand box at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your PayPal account will need to get [Enhanced Recurring Payments](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/ua/us-erp-full) option enabled for showing the card option during the checkout. Please contact PayPal Customer Service team for enabling ERP option.

If this option is not enabled, then there is no chance for guest checkout, in that case, you can't remove the text "You need a PayPal account for this purchase" at the checkout page. This is an intended behavior.